# vqmod opencart - dom unable to load error

Tags: opencart

I am using Opencart version 1.5.2.1. And vqmod of version 2.1.7.

And the problem is I am getting this, dom unable to load error with the file, ze-oc2ps-credits.xml

And the code is

```
<!-- Created using vQmod XML Generator by UKSB - http://www.opencart-extensions.co.uk //-->
<modification>
    <id><![CDATA[@tik Facebook Like Box]]></id>
    <version><![CDATA[1]]></version>
    <vqmver><![CDATA[2.1.6]]></vqmver>
    <author><![CDATA[OC2PS]]></author>
    </file>
        <file name="catalog/language/english/common/footer.php">
        <operation>
            <search position="replace" offset="1" error="skip"><![CDATA[$_['text_newsletter']   = 'Newsletter';]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[$_['text_newsletter']   = 'Newsletter';
$_['text_powered']      = 'Powered By <a href="http://www.opencart.com">OpenCart</a><br /> %s &copy; %s and <a href="http://www.csillamvilag.com">OC2PS</a>';]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>
</modification>
```

I wonder if someone could help me to find the problem ?

Thanks

Ajeesh

Answer (score 1):

The file is not entirely necessary for the mod to function, but the problem is the additional
`</file>` under author that is the problem.

```
    <!-- Created using vQmod XML Generator by UKSB - http://www.opencart-extensions.co.uk //-->
<modification>
    <id><![CDATA[@tik Facebook Like Box]]></id>
    <version><![CDATA[1]]></version>
    <vqmver><![CDATA[2.1.6]]></vqmver>
    <author><![CDATA[OC2PS]]></author>
    </file>   <<<<<<<<<<< This extra </file> is the problem bit. <<<<<<<<<<<<<
```

DOM unable to load errors are often caused by missing or additional tags such as the `<operation>` or `<file>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this happen a few times, and generally getting a "fresh" copy of the xml and uploading it will be enough. I would also recommend upgrading to the latest [vQmod](http://vqmod.com) version which has a number of features and improved performance

Answer (score 0):

This xml file serves no function except adding credit to the author.

I know, because I am him (the author of the extension and of this file).

To remove the link from your shop, just change the extension of the file from xml to xml_ (or delete the file altogether.

This file is packaged with all my free extensions for OpenCart. Earlier I used to include the credit in extensions' functional files, but figured that it was easier this way for folks to disable it if they didn't want it. (obviously I prefer if you keep the link...that's what motivates me to develop the free extensions)

I mention the link in documentation of all the extensions, and yet sometimes folks jump through hoops trying to figure out how this mysterious link appeared on their site. Sorry for the inconvenience. But really, it's about time you start reading documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I Was facing the similar problem. I had given the permission to the file. But still it was saying unable to load. After little research i found that it had admin permission and no read permission from others, which can be given by :

sudo chmod a+r filename

if you want to give to entire directory, then

sudo chmod -R a+r directory/

and this fixed my bug..

Hope it helps